# Plot View toolbar disappears in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have made a plot in matlab and the view toolbar appears on my plot (Zooming, Rotating, .... ) buttons. However, when I created a GUI and transfered my plot to gui axes handles, this toolbar disappears. How can I show this toolbar again in gui axes?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- working with `GUIDE` tool you enable it through the figure's `property inspector` setting:

  - `MenuBar` to display the figure `Menu`
  - `ToolBar` to display the toolbar for zoom, rotation etc.

[image]

- enable these properties directly in the GUI `.m` file: in the `OpeningFcn` (the GUI Opening function) you can set:

With the dot notation:

```
hObject.MenuBar='figure'
hObject.ToolBar='figure'
```

with the "old notation"

```
set(hObject,'MenuBar','figure')
set(hObject,'ToolBar','figure')
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'